# Ggplot2 - I can't insert the chart legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Good evening everybody, 
The data are:

```
Data      X     Y
01/01/16 17073 229
01/02/16 16094 375
01/03/16 17380 880
01/04/16 19993 9978
01/05/16 26290 24782
01/06/16 32982 36437
01/07/16 38490 42547
01/08/16 36688 43928
01/09/16 22799 36734
01/10/16 15000 11816
01/11/16 10494 680
01/12/16 10944 434
01/01/17 17217 235
01/02/17 15501 466
01/03/17 19236 1608
01/04/17 22239 8490
01/05/17 30390 23374
01/06/17 35579 34568
01/07/17 39613 43283
01/08/17 44089 44741
01/09/17 25542 35611
01/10/17 16357 10131
01/11/17 11754 541
02/12/17 11583 362
```

I have a little problem with my chart.

I wrote this code:

```
ggplot() 
+ geom_line(data=DB_Reg, aes(x=DB_Reg$Data,
 y=DB_Reg$X), color='435',size=0.5, show.legend = TRUE)+
geom_line(data=DB_Reg, aes(x=DB_Reg$Data, y=DB_Reg$Y),color='534',size=0.5, show.legend = TRUE)+
ggtitle("XY")+
  xlab("Dates")+
ylab("Quantity")+
geom_point()
```

[image]

I'd like to put the legend about the two lines. I wrote show.legend=TRUE for the two lines, but doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need the `DB_reg$` bits in your `aes` call, try removing those. Also if you can add some [minimal data and example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that will help us troubleshoot

Comment: I'm going to change.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ggplot` it is very important to ensure the code is written in the correct order. For example, adding `geom_point()` at the end is going to overwrite the previous argument. Try removing it. Here is a script that should work.

```
  ggplot(data=DB_Reg)+
  geom_line(mapping=aes(y=X,x= Data,color="X"),size=1 ) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(y=Y,x= Data,color="Y"),size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    'X' = 'darkblue',
    'Y' = 'red')) +
  labs(color = 'Y series')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I was not very orderly to write. 
Now It's working.

Comment: @Francesco I have updated my answer to include a script that should give you what you want

Answer (score 1):

It's good rule to add some data to reproduce your code.
Let's pretend data looks like

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

DB_Reg <- tibble(Data=seq(ymd('2016-01-01'),ymd('2016-12-31'), by = 1)) %>% 
  mutate(X=2+sin(yday(Data)/360*2*pi),
         Y=2+cos(yday(Data)/360*2*pi))
```

In order to be shown on legend, your parameters should be mapped in `aes()`.
To do this some data preparation needed.
Following code should give result you want:

```
DB_Reg %>% 
  gather(key = 'line', value = 'value', -Data) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Data, y=value, group=line, color=line))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('435', '534'))+
  ggtitle("XY")+
  xlab("Dates")+
  ylab("Quantity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry if I forgot to put the data.

Comment: @bdemarest thank you for edit! It's much more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see what your data is here, the main issue is that you plotted two data series separately, rather than providing `ggplot2` with a grouping variable in `aes()` (i.e. `color`, `shape`, or `group` ).

For example, if you were to plot `qsec ~ hp`, while grouping by the number of cylinders within the `mtcars` dataset, you want to specify all your aesthetics within the `ggplot()` function, as below:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars,
       aes(x = hp,
           y = qsec,
           color = as.factor(cyl)
           )
       ) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Horsepower Makes Cars Faster",
       x = "Quarter Mile Time (Seconds)",
       y = "Horsepower",
       color = "Number of Cylinders"
       )
```

The colors used for each group are `ggplot` defaults, but if you'd like to use a custom color palette, you can use the `scale_color_manual()` function;

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars,
       aes(x = hp,
           y = qsec,
           color = as.factor(cyl)
           )
       ) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Horsepower Makes Cars Faster",
       x = "Quarter Mile Time (Seconds)",
       y = "Horsepower",
       color = "Number of Cylinders"
       ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("4" = "firebrick",
                                "6" = "cornflowerblue",
                                "8" = "chartreuse3"
                                )
                     )
```

there are a number of ways to manually adjust your legend, but adding a grouping variableto `DB_Reg`, and specifying it with the `color` aesthetic should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry if I forgot to put the data.